# What does it mean to "redirect with token" for single sign on?

Tags: jwt, single-sign-on, bearer-token

(Background: I am trying to use my website hosted on wix as a simple identity provider so my members can access a separate sveltekit app I am creating--without logging in again--on a separate server because I do not think I can create the app on the wix platform. Basically I just need the user id, but I would like to also ensure they are in fact authenticated on my Wix hosted site before granting access).

In [multiple](https://blog.theodo.com/2019/07/single-sign-on/) [pages](https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-and-how-does-single-sign-on-work/) explaining single sign on, it is explained that when my browser requests a protected resource from a web server, the server can (if it is configured to do so) verify my identity via a separate identity provider. This is done via a redirect to the identify provider. If I am not authenticated by the identify provider, I am asked to authenticate (by entering username and password, or whatever).

Once I am authenticated (by logging in or by verifying the presence of a valid session id on the identify provider's server from a prior login), the identify provider then "redirects with token" or a "token can be passed to the original domain by a redirect" according to these web sites I have encountered.

**But what does it mean to "redirect with token"?** This conflicts with other reading I have done which points out that redirects cannot have authentication or other headers or data associated with them.

How does it come to pass that (1) the web server I made my original request from gets my token from the identify provider while at the same time (2) returning my requested resource to my browser instead of back to the identity provider's server?

Comment: The "redirect" can be a HTTP 3xx redirection and the token would be passed as a querystring parameter - but the redirect can also be a hidden cross-origin `<form>` POST with the token passed in an `<input type="hidden">` field - of course exposing a token directly is insecure so modern applications send a `code` parameter instead.

Comment: FIRST QUESTION: If you're using Wix for "identity", then this should be your first stop: https://support.wix.com/en/article/sso-setting-up-single-sign-on-sso-login.  NEXT QUESTION: what kind of "client" are users authenticating with?  A web app?  A ReactJS or Angular SPA? Other?  To answer your question: the "conceptual answer" is satraightforward...but specific implementation details could vary wildly, depending on a lot of different variables.

Comment: @paulsm4 yes, that is where I started. But I am not an enterprise customer so I have to roll my own SSO (which could include using third party platforms like auth0 which would be fine but feels like a sledge hammer for this particular nail). Clients are authenticating with web app (sveltekit based). My roadblock was understanding the conceptual details...I think I get it now so implementation should be straightforward enough. Thank you!

Comment: SUGGESTION: You could do worse than a) looking at "SK Auth": https://github.com/Dan6erbond/sk-auth, then b) trying out the example app.  Regardless of whether or not you wind up actually using this library .... I think you'll find it instructive.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Redirect with token" is a common method used in single sign-on (SSO) systems to authenticate users. In this method, when a user tries to access a protected resource on a server, the server redirects the user's browser to the SSO login page, along with a token that identifies the resource being accessed and the server that is requesting authentication.

The user then enters their login credentials on the SSO login page. If the credentials are correct, the SSO system authenticates the user and sends them back to the original server, along with a token that indicates that the user has been authenticated. The server checks the token to confirm that the user has been authenticated, and if the token is valid, the user is granted access to the protected resource.

Redirecting with a token is a secure and efficient way to authenticate users across multiple servers, as it allows the servers to rely on the SSO system to authenticate users and eliminates the need for each server to store and manage its own set of login credentials.

Comment: Thank you Anthony. Nice concise summary. My question is how the redirecting actually occurs since you can't have authentication headers or data associated with a redirect. The comments above suggest the mechanism is either query parameters along with the redirect or a POST response with hidden form elements. Right?

Comment: In my experince of using identity providers. The initial redirect (after sign in) back to the resource requesting access, doesn't contain the actually token that will be used to request resources. 

It's actually a code that you send to the identity provider with a POST request. You also will have to send a unique key (you normally get this when you setup the identity provider). If your code and other information sent to the provider is valid, it will return a token back that you can make resource request with.

Comment: I worked with a few identity providers but my main go to is Azure B2C. Here's a diagram of how that works. Which is normally the case for other providers.

[link](https://www.yuriburger.net/2020/11/05/azure-active-directory-b2c-with-pkce-for-your-angular-app/images/pkceflow.png)